# How to debug a ImageJ plugin in Emacs by using JDEE environment?

Tags: java, debugging, emacs, gdb, imagej

I am currently developing a plugin for ImageJ, it's based on Java. I am not familiar with Java much since I used to be a C/C++ developer. It seems that debugging java program has a lot of differences comparing using GDB/GUD in emacs. I know I can use Eclipse to deal with the debug but I just don't want to waste my time on learning another IDE. Thank you very much for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) for Emacs?

If you are planning on doing Java for more than a week I really advise you to use eclipse or netbeans. Yes it is a new IDE. But the advantages of this type of IDE for Java are immense.

Comment: yes.I tried JDEE but it is not so convenient. I am now switch to Eclipse. But it runs a little bit slow on my old Dell Optiplex GX220 with Ubuntu 11.04, especially displaying the menu.